# AndAlso not working in Linq Query vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have an array of structs (aryShooters()). I need to determine which post they are in and if they are active. If they are then I want to store which index they were at. If the post wasn't filled then the index to that spot in the array is set to -1. The problem I am having is that in my query where I check it then use AndAlso, isn't short-circuiting the rest of the line.

Here is where I set the indices:

```
Dim p1i as integer = -1
Dim p1i as integer = -1
Dim p1i as integer = -1
Dim p1i as integer = -1
Dim p1i as integer = -1
For j as integer = 0 to UBound(aryShooters)
    If aryShooters(j).active = true Then
        Select Case aryShooters(j).post
            Case 1
                p1i = j
            Case 2
                p2i = j
            Case 3
                p3i = j
            Case 4
                p4i = j
            Case 5
                p5i = j
        End Select
    End If
Next
```

And Immediately after that I call my Query. Its only the last 5 lines that are messing this up.

```
Dim pos
pos = From p In db.Banks
            Where p.ShootId = shootIdProp And p.EventId = eventNo _
            And ((p.FlightNo >= (CurFlight - kd)) And (p.FlightNo <= (CurFlight + (x-1) + ku))) _
            And ((p.SectionNo Like lowsec) Or (p.SectionNo like upsec)) _
            And p.Inactive = False And (((p.P1 like p1a And p.P2 Like p2a And p.P3 Like p3a And p.P4 Like p4a And p.P5 Like p5a) And resetFlags = False) _
            Or (( p.NmbrOpenPosts >= numberShooters) And resetflags = True)) _
            And ((((p1i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p1i).Ydg - p.HcpYds1) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds1 = 0.0))) And _
             (((p2i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p2i).Ydg - p.HcpYds2) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds2 = 0.0))) And _
             (((p3i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p3i).Ydg - p.HcpYds3) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds3 = 0.0))) And _
             (((p4i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p4i).Ydg - p.HcpYds4) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds4 = 0.0))) And _
             (((p5i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p5i).Ydg - p.HcpYds5) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds5 = 0.0))))
            Select p
```

EDIT - Well, I fixed it. Just added a blank spot in position 0. It can still reference it but never actually read it.

Comment: Why do you use  bitwise operators here at all?

Comment: @Magnus, How else would you suggest selecting in a query with lots of criteria as efficiently as possible? Wouldn't running the criteria through a huge if statement in the for each loop be less efficient than running it through the Linq/Sql which is meant for sorting through the table?

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using `AndAlso` and `OrElse` everywhere here?

Comment: Fairly, Positive. On all the other parts of the query, I don't care if it evaluates to false and continues. In some cases I HAVE to have it continue the expression no matter what. Also, that would give me the same issues, I am assuming as the current     AndAlso gives. With the current     AndAlso , it checks the index to see if it is greater than -1 which it will be if it isn't -1 and should terminate that and IFF the variable equals -1.

Comment: Because both `And` and `AndAlso` will be translated into `And` when the query is rendered into SQL. SQL's `And` is the same as VB's `AndAlso` (short-circuiting logical conjunction on two expressions)

Comment: @Magnus, You are correct that there is no 'AndAlso' in SQL but in Linq there is and the Linq to SQL translates it appropriately. See the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055815/does-and-vs-andalso-matter-with-linq-in-vb-net I have also read that the queries may not be ran in the order I wrote them in. Would it be possible that the part I don't want to run is somehow running before the index check?

Comment: Since SQL does not distinguish between `And` and `AndAlso` there is not reason to mix it in your query. You are also correct that SQL may not run the where condition in the order it is written, the query optimizer can rearrange it.

Comment: @Magnus, the point in writing the `AndAlso` like that is because the Linq does process that differently than just `And`. Is there possibly a different way that I could check the index in the query and not process the second statement if the first fails?

Comment: Linq2Sql does not process it differently. Linq2Objects does

Comment: @Magnus, O, I thought it did. Well is there a way to check the index and not process the second statement if the first fails?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help (I am not a vb expert): 
I think the line:

```
pos = From p In db.Banks
```

Should be like this:

```
pos = From p In db.Banks _
```

I think that the line:

```
Or (p.HcpYds5 = 0.0))))
            Select p
```

Should be like this:

```
Or (p.HcpYds5 = 0.0))) _ 
            Select p
```

And the last if statements you have a lot of parentheses that are not used. There for I think that the statement:

```
 And ((((p1i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p1i).Ydg - p.HcpYds1) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds1 = 0.0))) And _
             (((p2i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p2i).Ydg - p.HcpYds2) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds2 = 0.0))) And _
             (((p3i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p3i).Ydg - p.HcpYds3) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds3 = 0.0))) And _
             (((p4i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p4i).Ydg - p.HcpYds4) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds4 = 0.0))) And _
             (((p5i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p5i).Ydg - p.HcpYds5) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds5 = 0.0))))
            Select p
```

Should be like this:

```
And _ 
             ((p1i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p1i).Ydg - p.HcpYds1) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds1 = 0.0))) And _
             ((p2i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p2i).Ydg - p.HcpYds2) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds2 = 0.0))) And _
             ((p3i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p3i).Ydg - p.HcpYds3) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds3 = 0.0))) And _
             ((p4i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p4i).Ydg - p.HcpYds4) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds4 = 0.0))) And _
             ((p5i > -1) AndAlso ((Math.Abs(aryShooter(p5i).Ydg - p.HcpYds5) <= perTrap) Or (p.HcpYds5 = 0.0))) _ 
            Select p
```

Comment: There are lots of parentheses that seemed to be not used but are actually being used to group the and's & or's. The last "if" statement after the and is if all of those return true then it and's it with True. I don't have my other queries in from of me but they should all resemble the same way my original code posted above is. I will check to make sure that they do resemble other queries. But the code worked before when I wasn't using the AndAlso in my code and a different referencing method. This previous method was incorporated into the new array of structs.

Comment: Also the syntax that was posted in original context is correct as far as similar to other queries that work.